# Extjs form - findField is not defined

Tags: forms, extjs

I am selecting a form in Extjs as the following:

```
var form = Ext.getCmp(mainTabsId).getActiveTab().down().getForm("add-form");
//I am getting here the correct id.
console.log(form.id);
```

But when I am trying to find a field inside like that I am getting the following error:

```
form.findField("Address").getValue();

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findField'
```

this is the console.log of form http://pastebin.com/EuVizyCZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findField` is a method of [`Ext.form.Basic`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic), not `Ext.form.Panel`... So you have to do:

```
form.getForm() // get the BasicForm ref
    .findField('Address')
    .getValue();
```

**Update**

By guessing from your code, I would try:

```
// supposing add-form is the id or itemId of a FormPanel
Ext.getCmp(mainTabsId).getActiveTab().down('#add-form').getForm()
```

Comment: Thansk, same thing: getForm is not defined (have a look at the form output http://pastebin.com/EuVizyCZ) thanks

Comment: It seems that you have grabbed a DOM element... What version of Ext are you using? And what is this `getForm` method with arguments that you're using?

Comment: ok, this is what finally worked for me: `getActiveTab().down('window').down('#add-form').getForm()` I had a window inside. please tell me, is that ok to use the # or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, if 'add-form' is an `itemId` or `id`, the # is what you need to use.